# Raspberry PI, How to configure other GPIO to work as I2C

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am using the Raspberry PI for one of my projects.

In this project I need two different I2C interfaces to run simultaneously.
I know how to set the GPIO-0 and GPIO-1 to work as I2C (There is tutorials everywhere, ex: [one of the tutorials how to enable I2C in raspberry](http://www.skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/575)).

Also in this link [RPi Low-level peripherials](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals)it says that any GPIO can work as I2C.

How do I configure other GPIO's to work as I2C also so I can have to different interfaces in parallel. (I know I need to add pull-up resistors, but I don't know how to configure this in Linux shell or in C).
Can someone explain me in easy steps how this is done?

Thanks, 
Adrian.

Comment: This should of been asked at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This has been asked and [answered on RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88151/83790)

Answer (score 2):

I made an i2c bit banging bus interface on top of wiringPi. You can make a bus out of any 2 GPIO Pins. It is written in C++ but should be easily portable to C. Most functions are C anyways. Maybe it needs some polish, but at least it is a starting point.

https://github.com/robotrovsky/rpi_i2c_bit_banging

Comment: hi @robotrovsky, for some reason, i have to do my own i2c bit-banging on RPi as well, ... did you config RPi gpios for open-drain mode? & used pull-up resistor for them?
coz i've been surveying some Q&A on the web, some of them mentioned these methods ... but i cannot find how to config RPi gpios in open-drain mode...

Comment: Hi Seagal! I2C bus 1 (gpios 2 and 3 on rpi2 pins 3 and 5) have hard-wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3. http://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin3_gpio2 Click on the pins to see the specification. When you want to use i2c-bit-banging on other GPIO-Pins you need external pull-up resistors. I didn't configure the other gpios, i just used external pull-ups for them. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I found no need to worry about "configuring" open-drain mode. Just make sure to config gpio for SDA as IN/OUT when we need it acts as IN/OUT. And the root cause of why i asked the question: I forgot to send 1 SCL cycle clock for attached device to let device ack clock in!
Briefly followed sample codes on these 2 sites got my i2cbitbanging worked. http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Example_of_bit-banging_the_I2C_Master_protocol .And, yes, if i use gpio2 & 3, need no worry about pull up resistor, if using other GPIOs, then it's needed. Thx Anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If the pins has no hardware implemented I2C driver, a software implementation could be implemented using the concept of [bit-banging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging).

Comment: That is right. Try to implement your own I2C shiftting bits. It is not so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you could try bitbanging. If you are experienced in soldering you could "hardware-hack" the pi as the second I2C bus lies on the camera interface.

See

http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Raspberry-Pi-R2.0-Schematics-Issue2.2_027.pdf

Page 4 S5

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want two i2c buses?
You can run multiple devices on the same i2c bus, as long as they have different addresses.  And most components let you change the address by soldering up two pads.

Comment: Sometimes you need each bus to run at a different clock speed.

Answer (score -1):

You can create aditional i2c busses on any gpio pins

https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/

Comment: Please, share the main thought from the article here.